# Validate if a user exists in Active Directory in Asp.net web api core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I **check the user is exist or not in Active Directory**.
we are **passing emailId as userName** to the method **parameter** and it is GET method.

We have written this method, but it is not working properly.

```
[HttpGet("GetADUsers")]
public List<string> GetADUsers(string userName)
{
        var domainUsers = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            string domainName = _domainSettings.Value.DomainName;
            string domainUserName = _domainSettings.Value.UserName;
            string domainPassword = _domainSettings.Value.Password;

            PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, domainUserName, domainPassword, ContextOptions.SimpleBind.ToString());

            UserPrincipal principalUser = new UserPrincipal(pc);

            using (var search = new PrincipalSearcher(principalUser))
            {
                foreach (var user in search.FindAll().Where(x => x.DisplayName == userName))
                {
                    if (user.DisplayName != null)
                    {
                        domainUsers.Add(user.DisplayName);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Message.ToString();
        }

        return domainUsers;
    }
```

Comment: Your mistake is comparing the `userName` to the `DisplayName`. You should probably be comparing it to the `SamAccountName` property, which is the username in AD. But the answer by marc_s will likely be a faster search anyway.

Comment: Thanks, Gabriel Luci for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you've created the `PrincipalContext`, you could just call `UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity()` - if the user is found, you get back the `UserPrincipal` - otherwise null.

```
[HttpGet("GetADUsers")]
public bool ADUserExists(string userName)
{
    string domainName = _domainSettings.Value.DomainName;
    string domainUserName = _domainSettings.Value.UserName;
    string domainPassword = _domainSettings.Value.Password;

    PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName, domainUserName, domainPassword, ContextOptions.SimpleBind.ToString());

    UserPrincipal principalUser = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, userName);

    if (principalUser != null) 
    {
         // gefunden ....            
         return true;
    }
    else
    {
         // nicht gefunden  
         return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You Buddy for the solution